# My active class momentarily goes to the next link only to go back to the previous one after page finishes to load

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried other solutions presented on the same question but none seems to work for my code.

That's my html

```
<div class="col-md-3 profile-sidebar">
                <div class="avatar-wrap d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <a href="">
                        <img src="{% static 'img/avatar.svg' %}" alt="{{ post.created_by.username }}"
                             class="circular w-100"> </a>
                    <span class="avatar-online"></span>
                </div>
                <h4 class="profile-meta">
                    <small class="profile-user-title">Team member</small>
                </h4>
                <div class="list-group nav-side">
                    <a class="list-group-item"
                       href="{% url 'users:user_posts' user.username user.pk %}">
                        <i class="fas fa-comment-alt fa-fw"></i> Posts</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item "
                       href="{% url 'users:user_topics' user.username user.pk %}">
                        <i class="fab fa-forumbee fa-fw"></i> Topics</a>
                </div>
```

And my script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a").click(function () {
            $(".nav-side a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript runs when you click the link. It changes the classes.

Then the browser follows the link and loads the new page.

That's a different page.

The changes you made to the *previous* page are not visible in the new one.

Use server-side code to set the class instead.